# How does one determine active SSH and SAMBA connection counts?

Tags: linux, ssh, samba, cron, login

I have a server that I use infrequently, so I'd like to `cron` a job to shutdown daily if no users are logged in via SSH and SAMBA shares.

***How can I determine how many active SSH connections there are, and how many active SAMBA connections there are?***

If both of these values are zero, the cron script will shutdown the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Active ssh connection:

```
# netstat -an | grep -E "\:22[ \t]+" | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
1
```

Active Samba connection:

```
# netstat -an | grep -E "\:445[ \t]+" | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l
```

or use lsof:

```
SSHCONNECTION=`lsof -i :22 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`
SAMBACONNECTION=`lsof -i :445 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l`
echo "SSH connection: ${SSHCONNECTION} Samba connection ${SAMBACONNECTION}"
```

Comment: Consider `grep -c ESTABLISHED` instead of filtering all those through `wc -l`

Answer (score 2):

You can check any active connections to any service by using the following command

`netstat -an | grep ESTABLISHED | grep ":[portname] " | wc -l`

By portname you need to select the port of the service you're looking into, for SSH that'll be port 22 (so it should be `grep ":22 "`) (the space behind just makes sure that it's not another port.

If you want to select more than one port (as it would be in samba) change grep for `egrep ":(port|port|port) "`