# Is there a way to determine if a SAMBA share has open files?

Tags: linux, windows, samba

This is [related](https://serverfault.com/questions/228852/how-does-one-determine-active-ssh-and-samba-connection-counts) to an effort to shutdown a seldom used server if there are no SSH connections or open files.

How can I determine in a shell script (cron job on a Linux box) if any of the current samba shares have any open files?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your samba server is configured to use file locking which is probably is, I suppose you could use 'smbstatus -L' to list the locks and then grep the output for the type of lock you're looking for (EXCLUSIVE, BATCH) if you knew you only cared about certain kinds of locks.

Something like:

smbstatus -L | grep EXCLUSIVE

and then test against the return value ($?) in the cron job script.

Unfortunately, I don't know enough about the types of locks to know if this is a suitable catch-all method or not.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably use the lsof command to determine what files are in use on the share.

`lsof | grep /path/to/share` should show files in use.

Comment: This doesn't work with Samba (at the least with the version  4.2.14). `lsof` just reports the local directory which is shared with the network, but does not list the opened files that reside under the directory/share.

Answer (score 0):

cense's answer is good, and his thing about the locks applies to this answer. Samba also allows read only status (I think it shows up as RD_ONLY), and also displays entries for directories that are open in Windows Explorer, so you have to decide what kind of locks you want to ignore/focus on.

I believe the output of `smbstatus` is `No machines connected.`, if, well, no machines are connected, so you could possibly use something like `smbstatus|grep No\ machines\ connected && shutdown` to shutdown when nothing's connected.

To the best of my knowledge (No access to a Samba server right now), if you have a Samba share mounted in Windows, `smbstatus` will show that the Windows machine has connected, even if the user isn't actively using the share, so you'll probably need to decide what to do based on that case too.